# Angular: return URL ERROR : The requested URL was not found on this server

Tags: html, angular, redirect

I have an issue, I have a website in which the return to the previous page generate this error:

```
The requested URL was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the 
request.
```

That happen when in my site I click to a link that direct me to another external url; and then when I click to go back to my page

This is how I set my route in angular:

```
export const appRoutes: Routes = [

{path: 'users', component: UsersListComponent},
{path: 'products', component: ProductListComponent},
{path: '**', redirectTo: 'users', pathMatch: 'full'}
];
```

When I build my app, I have this is what I see as as my basepath in my `index.html`

```
 <title>ProductsWebApp</title>
 <base href="/">
```

I also want to specify that the page does exist
What could be the problem?

Comment: Does this help? https://angular.io/guide/deployment#server-configuration

Comment: can you share your initial URL screenshot when it is working, then after you navigate to another and return (kindly show image)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally fixed my problem by adding the following to my `.htaccess` file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d

    RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*) index.html [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

More information can be found on in this [link](https://gist.github.com/julianpoemp/bcf277cb56d2420cc53ec630a04a3566)

Comment: This seemed to work for me for only one componenent